# how to make a console cmd for Qt app in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

I made a basic text editor(called 'Note') in Qt on Arch Linux! so I built the project and made an installer using installjammer. now when I type note in terminal it opens the program. 
Now here is my question:
if we use nano or leafpad or mousepad it take the path of the file opens it.
Eg. nano /etc/fstab
how can I do this in my program? do I need to edit something in the installer or in my codes? HELP ME! pls! 
~Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read the docs for QCoreApplication. Especially:
QStringList QCoreApplication::arguments()

Get the filename from this ist, open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Get the passed command line argument either directly in main() from the `argv` argument, or through QCoreApplication::arguments(). [This is well documented](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#accessing-command-line-arguments) and should be rather easy. The tricky part is actually opening the file. For that, you need to schedule a slot for running right after you call exec() on your QApplication instance. First, create a slot. For example, if you're subclassing QApplication, you can:

```
class MyApplication: public QApplication {
    Q_OBJECT
    // ...

    private slots:
        void checkCmdLine();

    // ...
};
```

In your MyApplication::checkCmdLine() function you get the arguments from QCoreApplication::arguments() and check whether a filename was passed. If yes, you open it.

Now you need to make sure that MyApplication::checkCmdLine() will run right after you call exec() on MyApplication. You do that in your main() function by using [QMetaObject::invokeMethod()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-3). For example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyApplication* app = new MyApplication(argc, argv);
    // ...

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(app, "checkCmdLine", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    app->exec();
    // ...
}
```

If you're not subclassing QApplication, then you can implement the slot in some other QObject subclass and use QMetaObject::invokeMethod() on that instead.

Comment: ???? Why so complicated? Just open the file with QFile in the constructor of whatever object you instantiate before app->exec().

Comment: @Greenflow With C++, I don't recommend doing complicated things in the constructor. You should only initialize the object there and nothing else. Once all constructors returned (inherited ones as well as new ones from possible subclasses) only then can the object be considered fully initialized.

Comment: @Nicos C. More complicated than subclass QApplication? An yes, what I proposed was just initializing an object, with the name of the file to open. He wants to do something with a filename given on the commandline, the program is just started to do something with this file, so I think it is perfectly ok, to get this name during creation. I do understand your point, it might be correct from a OO point of view, but.... You can exaggerate everything. ;-)

Comment: @Greenflow When I instruct/teach/mentor people, I always pay attention to good coding practices. A constructor is not there to do heavy lifting, which can happen when you call a function in it. A constructor should only do the minimum that's necessary to initialize the object. It doesn't matter if the application in question is small or not; correct coding is important regardless of how big a project is :-)

Comment: I agree with Greengflow if that matters. :-)

Comment: I think subclassing QApplication is unnecesary. This code can be in a QObject subclass.

Comment: @KubaOber Yep, any QObject will do. This is already mentioned in the last paragraph of the answer :-)