# Retrieving command line arguments in a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt

I want to do something like from the Unix command prompt:

```
./countHats("red")   or 
./countHats "red"
```

and then the program runs and counts up red hats.

How can I do that?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100,100), QSize(1000,500)));

    CHat *hat = new CHat();
    hat->color(argv[0]);//"red"   ????

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278538/how-to-make-a-console-cmd-for-qt-app-in-linux

Comment: I would not call it 'unfortunate'. The 'invokeMethod' comment is a perfect textbook solution. I can think of use cases, where it is clearly superior. But part of development is also to know, when something is overkill. ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You better use [`QCoreApplication::arguments`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#arguments)

Basically, you would need to use it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100,100), QSize(1000,500)));

    CHat *hat = new CHat();
    hat->color(QCoreApplication::arguments().at(1));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Then you invoke the following command: `./countHats red`. There is no need for quotes in this particular case, nor for brackets, although it will work with quotes, too.

You would need the quotes if you have an argument that contains spaces, and so forth, which is not the case with the very simple colors, and for a bit more, you would need color code management, anyhow.

---

PS, why we are at it, you should use a better name for your setter like `setColor`. `color()` is usually used for getting the value of the color, not setting that, but that is slightly off-topic now. I just wished to help you with pointing that out, too.

Also, you do not seem to delete the hat, and it does not take part in the Qt parent/child relationship either to get automatically deleted. You would need to improve this bit, too.

Note however that me and David Faure have been working on a `QCommandLineParser` class which you can hopefully use from Qt5.2 on. Changes are now being reviewed on gerrit for integration.

Answer (score 2):

code should be argv[1]...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100,100), QSize(1000,500)));

    CHat *hat = new CHat();
    hat->color(argv[1]);//"red"   ????  -->  argv[1]

    return a.exec();
}
```

this works for the commandLine:

```
./countHats "red"   or 
./countHats red
```

Comment: Better use `QApplication::arguments` http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#arguments

Answer (score 2):

First of all for any app in C/C++: first element of argv is name of the program, so argv[0] will be "countHats" not "red". And If You want to have more command line arguments I recommend using boost::program_options library, it's quite easy to use and very powerful.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: I do not think introducing an additional dependency just for this small feature makes so much sense, especially when it is a Qt application. There could be clashing issues, like keywords and forth. Those would require further solutions. Also, argv[0] is not necessarily always countHats, just usually.

Comment: I totally agree, that's why I said "if You want to have more command line arguments" not in this exact case, but if You want to have named options (like -c for color of hats, and -s for size and so on). Can You give example of a case when argv[0] is not name of the program? I'm quite a beginner myself, so I'll be glad to learn new thing :) .

Comment: Even if you wanted more, you would not mix boost with qt. That is a bit unthoughtful just for this. You would probably use a clone of QCommandLineParser that I already mentioned in my reply, or just directly from Qt 5.2 on. As for the argv[0] being different, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288028/what-will-be-the-output-of-the-program